# jQuery - event that a user edited the content of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery and make an iteration over a list of projects. Every project is put on the screen and it is draggable. Also very project has a textarea.

Source code:

```
$.each(data, function(id, project) {
    $('#projects').append('<div class="note" data-projectid="'+project.id+'"><textarea class="edit">'+project.text+'</textarea></div>');
});
$(".note").draggable({
    containment: "#projects", 
    scroll: false
});
```

What I want, is to know if a user change the text of the project, so I need to know if the cursor leaves the textarea. And I need to know the new text and the data-projectid, so I can save the new text (into a database which is located in the backend system).

Thank you in advance for your help, Tim-.

Comment: Are you sure "if the cursor leaves the textarea" means they changed the text?  What if they are using the keyboard only?

Comment: I think "if the focus is lost", is the better defintion for what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're saying you want to know if the user edited the content of the `<textarea>` elements, place [a `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler on the `#projects` element that listens for a `change` event in the `textarea.edit` elements.

```
$('#projects').delegate('textarea.edit','change',function() {
    alert('was changed');
});
```

Do this only once when the page loads. It will work for all `<textarea>` elements that you append to the `#projects` container.

Comment: I believe 'change','textarea.edit' should be 'textarea.edit','change'

Comment: @idealmachine: You're right. I had it flipped, then I overwrote your correction when I was making another edit. Then I meant to revert back to yours, but instead went back to my original. Fixed now. Thanks. :o)

Comment: but how can I access the `data-projectid` or should I put this also in the textarea, and then access it with `$(this).data("projectid")`?

Comment: @Tim: Inside the handler, use `$(this).parent().data("projectid")`, assuming you're using jQuery 1.4.3 or later. If not, use `$(this).parent().attr("data-projectid")`.

Answer (score 2):

When text changes, the [`onchange`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event takes place and when cursor leaves it, the [`onblur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event is triggered:

```
$('.edit').change(function(){
  alert(this.value);
});

$('.edit').blur(function(){
  // cursor left text area
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify... onchange is fired when the user edits the text *then* the cursor leaves the input. So it's just like onblur except there's an extra test which checks if the text is the same as it was before.

Comment: the `blur` function works, but I also need the data-projectid. Normally I can access it with `$(this).data("projectid")`

Comment: @Tim: Since it is an attribute of the tag, you can try this instead: `$('div.note').attr('data-projectid')`

Comment: This returns an `undefined`. There are many of this elements on the screen, so it probably does not know which of them is 'blured' - Update: my fault, it returns always the first element which matches and not the element which was edited.

Answer (score 1):

the event you're looking for is .blur() , this event executes when a element looses focus, so for ex.

```
$.each(data, function(id, project) {
    $('#projects').append('<div class="note" data-projectid="'+project.id+'"><textarea class="edit">'+project.text+'</textarea></div>');
    $('textbox').blur(function() {
        $(this).val(); //gives you the current value of the box.
        //then do what you need with that info. also the project obj is still available to get project.id from
        var data-projectid = project.id

    });
});
```

Comment: this works for me, but how can I access here the data-projectid?

Comment: I updated the code to be inside the context of your $.each() giving you access to the project obj just like in your append.

Comment: I need the value of `data-projectid` if the user leave the textarea, because I have to update the database content, and therefore I will need the ID.

Comment: hah, I don't think you're hearing me...   just like you have set the data-projectid in your append statement with 'project.id', you also have access to 'project.id' in your .blur() event handler.  I'll edit the source code to reflect this.